# itextpdf: loadLicenseFile issue

Tags: itext7

I'm on just started to play with itextpdf 7.2.2, and I see an issue while trying to load my trial license. Here is the code snapshot:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public void loadItextLicense() {
    try {
        String licenseFileName = "classpath:licenses/ae2b7b01aa4d3b744f5873d3e3b66182bce5fd6bc0cd4993b0504aabab7882ef.json";
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(licenseFileName);
        File lFile = resource.getFile();
        log.info("File exists? " + lFile.exists());
        LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(lFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ItextService error: ", e);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.util.JsonUtil$CustomPrettyPrinter.(JsonUtil.java:135)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.util.JsonUtil.serializeToString(JsonUtil.java:44)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.util.SigningUtil.getExpectedSignature(SigningUtil.java:67)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.util.SigningUtil.checkSignature(SigningUtil.java:52)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.actions.LoadLicenseEvent.validateLicenceFile(LoadLicenseEvent.java:118)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.actions.LoadLicenseEvent.getProperLicenseFile(LoadLicenseEvent.java:100)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.actions.LoadLicenseEvent.(LoadLicenseEvent.java:42)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LicenseKey.java:151)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.LicenseKey.loadListOfLicenses(LicenseKey.java:202)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LicenseKey.java:129)
at com.itextpdf.licensing.base.LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LicenseKey.java:88)
at com.cchs.microservice.contract.service.impl.ItextService.loadItextLicense(ItextService.java:26)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Q: Are you using the new, JSON-format licenses, not the old XML-format files?

Comment: Can you please share your pom.xml file?